# PowerShell - Return value from source CSV to CSV if value in column X exist

Tags: powershell

I never wrote a PowerShell script before, so I created the next script with the help of many different google searches :) so it might be a little patchy, I am by no means a "scripter"

**To sum up I need to create a report of emails sent by specific mailboxes and return the data into Excel with this headers: time sent, sender, display name, recipients, subject.**

- I need help with adding the display name from the $output file

This is the what I created so far:

```
#Variables:
$output = "C:\temp\Source.csv"
$Unfiltered = "C:\temp\ReportUnfiltered.csv"
$UnfilteredV2 = "C:\temp\ReportV2.csv"
$CSVreport = "C:\temp\ReportV3.csv"
$finaleReportX = "C:\temp\finalReport.xlsx"
$To = "user@domain.com"
$desiredColumns = 'Date','Time','Sender','DisplayName','Recipients','MessageSubject'

#Create Source file:
get-mailbox -resultsize unlimited | where {$_.primarysmtpaddress -like "sales*"} | Select @{N='primarysmtpaddress';E={$_.primarysmtpaddress[0]}},displayname | export-csv $output -NoTypeInformation

$query = Import-Csv -Path $output

#Create Report for sent:
foreach ($Address in $query) {
Get-MessageTrackingLog -server exchange.domain.com -Start (get-date).addhours(-24) -end (Get-Date) -sender $Address.primarysmtpaddress | 
where-object {$_.EventID -eq ‘RECEIVE’} |
Select Timestamp,sender,@{Name='Recipients';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.Recipients))}},MessageSubject,MessageID | 
export-csv $Unfiltered -NoTypeInformation -encoding utf8 -Append
}

#Fix Timestamp:
Import-Csv $Unfiltered | 
Select-Object *,
        @{n='Date';e={$_.Timestamp.Split(" ")[0]}},
        @{n='Time';e={$_.Timestamp.Split(" ")[1]}} |
export-csv $UnfilteredV2 -NoTypeInformation -encoding utf8

# Selects desired columns
Import-Csv $UnfilteredV2 | Select $desiredColumns |
Export-Csv -Path $CSVreport –NoTypeInformation -encoding UTF8

# Export to Excel
Import-Csv $CSVreport | Select $desiredColumns |
Export-Excel -Path $finaleReportX | Format-Table –AutoSize

#Send Final Report:
$email = @{
From = "Report@domain.com"
To = $To
subject = “Report for All sent items"
SMTPserver = "exchange.domain.com"
Body = "See the attached Report"
Attachment = $finaleReportX
}
send-mailmessage @email

# Delete Reports From Local Drive
Remove-Item –path $output –recurse
Remove-Item –path $Unfiltered –recurse
Remove-Item –path $UnfilteredV2 –recurse
Remove-Item –path $CSVreport –recurse
Remove-Item –path $finaleReportX –recurse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a lot of in-between csv files and load them back in. I don't think this is necessary if you combine all queries in a single `ForEach-Object{}` loop with a `foreach()` loop inside that.

Also, because of copy/paste from the internet, there were some curly 'smart-quotes' in the code (`“`, `”`). Lots of times, PowerShell can handle that, but it is always better to use straight quotes `"` and `'` in code.

Something like this:

```
# Variables:
$to            = 'user@domain.com'
$from          = 'Report@domain.com'
$smtpServer    = 'exchange.domain.com'
$finaleReportX = 'C:\temp\finalReport.xlsx'

$today         = Get-Date
$yesterday     = $today.AddHours(-24)

# Create Report for email. Gather everything in a variable
$result = Get-Mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited | 
            Where-Object {$_.primarySmtpAddress -like "sales*"} | 
            ForEach-Object {
                $emailAddress  = @($_.primarySmtpAddress)[0]
                $displayName   = $_.DisplayName
                $trackingLog   = Get-MessageTrackingLog -Server exchange.domain.com -Start $yesterday -End $today -Sender $emailAddress |
                                   Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 'RECEIVE'}
                # loop through the items in the tracking log and create objects from that
                $trackingItems = foreach ($item in $trackingLog) {
                    $date, $time = $item.Timestamp -split ' '
                    # output an object with the desired properties to be collected in variable $trackingItems
                    [PsCustomObject]@{
                        Date           = $date
                        Time           = $time
                        DisplayName    = $displayName
                        Sender         = $item.Sender
                        Recipients     = $item.Recipients -join ';'
                        MessageSubject = $item.MessageSubject
                        # MessageID    = $item.MessageID  # usure if you want this in your report aswell..
                    }
                }
                # output the in-between results to be collected in variable $result
                $trackingItems
            }


# Export to Excel file
$result | Export-Excel -Path $finaleReportX -Title 'Email tracking log' -AutoSize

# Send Final Report:
$email = @{
    From        = $from
    To          = $to
    Subject     = 'Report for All sent items'
    SMTPserver  = $smtpServer
    Body        = 'See the attached Report'
    Attachments = $finaleReportX
}

Send-MailMessage @email

# Delete Report From Local Drive
Remove-Item -Path $finaleReportX
```